# Sub Categories in Document Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online

Good morning

Quick question, I have a document library on my site which has categories and sub-categories.  When I assign a category to an uploaded file thats fine, however when displayed on the page sub category also appears but with unassigned.

For example

Category: text
     
Sub-Category: Unassigned
                   
Filename

Is there anyway of removing the Sub-Category when there isn't one required (when I do require a sub-category it fine, just when I don't it looks messy).  I'm using SharePoint Online

I hope that makes sense

TIA

Comment: This question is little unclear. Can you please attach some screen-shots of what you are intending to do. This will help us to understand better

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for that.  So under arrivals/clearances I have a sub category which i've had to put something into (in this case a :) in order to have it not display unassigned.  What I want is that if there is no need to have a sub-category not to have it appear.  So in the image below under Arrivals/Clearances, there should just be a file.

The Establishments category is correct as a sub-category is required.

Is that clearer - thats not me being sarcastic btw, sometimes I find it hard to explain what I mean.

[image]